# What is the syntax in python to write strings and numbers to file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I trying to do the following:

```
f = open("file", "w")
index = 1
f.write("my_index is: %d\n", index)
```

but I get the following error:

```
f.write("my_index is: %d\n", index)
TypeError: write() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

How can I fix it? I tried the syntax of c..

Comment: `write` needs a single parameter which the content to be written in the file. What should `ìndex` represent?

Comment: `print(help(open('file_name', 'w').write))`

Comment: @cards So how can I do it ?

Comment: @cards index is loop-index that i need anytime to print the new value of it

Comment: just use an f-string `f.write(f'my index is {index}')`

Comment: Python has many different way for string formatting, in your case would be `write("my_index is: %d\n" % ìndex)`, separate with `%`

Answer (score 0):

You could concatenate it like

```
f = open("file.txt", "w")
index = 1
f.write("my_index is:\n"+ str(index))
```

or use an f string

```
f = open("file.txt", "w")
index = 2
f.write(f"my_index is:\n{index}")
```

Comment: `%d` above is intended as the value of index I believe

Comment: @bn_ln Ah yeah, I'll update the answer